# Testing Web Service on Multiple Environments

Tags: wcf, web-services, testing

I have been working on an application using visual studio where the application has 2 distinct web services developed in WCF. I have also written a number of functional test methods in Microsoft Test Project that calls each method in the web service to make sure they are working as expected.

The challenge I have is how should I go and test the web service at different stages (development machine, quality, staging and finally Live) without having to replicate the same tests for different environments?

Ideally such a solution should make it easier to automate the tests using a continuous integration.

Comment: So, your question is how to automatically set the service endpoint inside your tests according to the Environment they are currently executed?

Comment: yes exactly. you summed it up really nicely. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to it

1) For each service, you must save any environment-related information(URLs, database connection strings etc) in the app.config file. For example, each test should get the service URL from the same app config file. This way when you need to run your tests in different environments, all you need to do is to change the URL in the app config and run your tests.

2) For Continuous integration, you will need some sort of tooling to orchestrate this. You can use Jenkins to update the app configs to whatever environment build gets deployed.

Let me know if you need more details on how to do it.